# Data migrations in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a data migration for a Django app to populate
the main table in the db with data that will form the mainstay of
the app - this is persistent/permanent data that may added to but
never deleted.

My reference is the Django 1.7 documentation and in particular an
example on page

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython

with a custom method called forward_funcs:

```
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):

# We get the model from the versioned app registry;
# if we directly import it, it'll be the wrong version

Country = apps.get_model("myapp", "Country")
db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
Country.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
Country(name="USA", code="us"),
Country(name="France", code="fr"),])
```

I am assuming the argument to `bulk_create` is a list of `Country` model objects not `namedtuple` objects, although the format looks exactly the same.  Is this the case, and could someone please explain what `db_alias` is?

Also, if I wish to change or remove existing entries in a table using a data migration what are the methods corresponding to `bulk_create` to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Country is just the same as you would do `from app.models import Country`. Only thing different, the import always gives you the latest model and `apps.get_model` in a migration gives you the model at the time of the migration. It continues to edit the model within the initial migration.

About bulk_create; its argument is indeed a list of unsaved `Country` objects and uses it to do an huge insert into your db. More information about bulk_create can be found here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create.

About `db_alias`, it is the name of the database you set within your settings. Most of the time it is `default`, so you can leave it in your code if you just use one database. The function will probably will called more than once if you have more databases set within your settings. More info about `using`; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#using.

An bulk delete is actually quite simple, you just filter your Countries and call delete on the queryset. So something like;

```
Country.objects.filter(continent="Europe").delete()
```

About the persistent/permanent data question, I don't really have a solution for that one. One thing you can do, I think, is overwrite the .delete() function on the model and Manager.